# Group by multiple attributes across multiple nodes from XML with XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I have the following XML.

How I can group my elements by the group name in xslt 1.0? I need to group the values based on communs_params adress, price and vat. The other params (type) must be grouped under different_params

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<productsGrouppe>
 <product>
  <adressParam> 
   <parameter name="adress" >
     <value>street 1 </value>
   </parameter>
  </adressParam> 
  <priceParam>
   <parameter name="price" >
     <value>100 EUR </value>
   </parameter>
   <parameter name="vat" >
     <value> 1 </value>
   </parameter>
  </priceParam> 
  <deliveryParam>
    <parameter name="type" >
     <value> post </value>
   </parameter>
  </deliveryParam>
 </product>
 <product>
  <adressParam> 
   <parameter name="adress" >
     <value>street 2 </value>
   </parameter>
  </adressParam> 
  <priceParam>
   <parameter name="price" >
     <value>200 EUR </value>
   </parameter>
   <parameter name="vat" >
     <value> 2 </value>
   </parameter>
  </priceParam> 
  <deliveryParam>
    <parameter name="type" >
     <value> E-mail </value>
   </parameter>
  </deliveryParam>
 </product>
<product>
  <adressParam> 
   <parameter name="adress" >
     <value>street 1 </value>
   </parameter>
  </adressParam> 
  <priceParam>
   <parameter name="price" >
     <value>100 EUR </value>
   </parameter>
   <parameter name="vat" >
     <value> 1 </value>
   </parameter>
  </priceParam> 
  <deliveryParam>
    <parameter name="type" >
     <value> selfcollectors </value>
   </parameter>
  </deliveryParam>
 </product>
</productsGrouppe>
```

Expected Result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<productsGrouppe>
 <product>
   <commun_params>
     <value>street 1 </value>
     <value>100 EUR </value>
     <value> 1 </value>
   </commun_params>
   <different_params>
     <value> post </value>
      <value> selfcollectors </value>
   </different_params>
 </product>
</productsGrouppe>
```

Comment: I suggest you start here: http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html Then come back if you run into actual problems implementing this.

Answer (score 0):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:key name="product_adress" match="adressParam/parameter[@name='adress']/value" use="."/>

    <xsl:variable name="priceparam_price" select="priceParam/parameter[@name='price']/value"></xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="priceparam_vat" select="priceParam/parameter[@name='vat']/value"></xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="adressParam_adress" select="adressParam/parameter[@name='adress']/value"></xsl:variable>

    <xsl:template match="productsGrouppe">
        <product>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="product/adressParam/parameter[@name='adress']/value[generate-id(.)=generate-id(key('product_adress',.)[1])]"/>
        </product>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="product">

            <xsl:for-each select="key('product_adress', $adressParam_adress)">
                <commun_params>
                    <value><xsl:value-of select="$adressParam_adress" /></value>
                    <value><xsl:value-of select="$priceparam_price" /></value>
                    <value><xsl:value-of select="$priceparam_vat" /></value>
                </commun_params>
            </xsl:for-each>

    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

and that was the result:

street 1 street 2